# How to create an instance of the mixer config rule?

Tags: istio

I have to create programatically an instance of the mixer config Rule. Normally I would use a clientset for that, but here I can't find anything like that. Can someone point out to such clientset if it exists, or suggest how it should be handled in this particular case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, all the Istio configuration files can be handled by both `istioctl` and `kubectl`. `istioctl` adds validation of the configuration items on top of `kubectl`. So you can work with the Istio configuration items in the same way you work with `kubectl` items. You can test your configuration items first with `kubectl` and if it works with `kubectl` you can implement adding them programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware that I can do it in the standard way using `kubectl` command. Moreover I know that I can do it via an HTTP call too. I'm implementing a custom controller and was wondering if it is possible to do it in a way similar to:

`c.kubeClientset.ExtensionsV1beta1().Ingresses("my-namespace").Create(createIngress())`